# React Native WebView Generating invalid render method, says undefined

Tags: webview, react-native

I'm trying to use Canvas taken from https://github.com/iddan/react-native-canvas
However, when trying to generate, it seems that the WebView creates the following error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of 'Canvas'
```

I've attached A snippet from the index.ios.js containing Canvas. Any help as to why the WebView generates this error would be super helpful (It works if you remove WebView and just leave View).

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component, WebView } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Platform,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';
import SignatureCapture from 'react-native-signature-capture';
const Sound = require('react-native-sound');


// TEST
class Canvas extends Component {

  propTypes: {
    context: React.PropTypes.object,
    render: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  render() {

    var contextString = JSON.stringify(this.props.context);
    var renderString = this.props.render.toString();

    return (
      <View>
        <WebView
          automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
          contentInset={{top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0}}
          html={'<style>*{margin:0;padding:0;}canvas{position:absolute;transform:translateZ(0);}</style><canvas></canvas><script>var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");(" + renderString + ").call(" + contextString + ", canvas);</script>'}
          opaque={false}
          underlayColor={'transparent'}
          style={this.props.style}/>
      </View>
    );
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of RN are you using? On 0.42 it says html prop is deprecated so you would have to use `source={html: string, baseUrl: string}`. Also I think it might be having trouble defining one of your jsx elements, I'm thinking it might be the

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your html code in a file and call `source={{ uri: require('./myfile.html')}}` . Use source prop instead html. html is deprecated. Verify the docs https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html